# facetime - AutoAcceptInvites

Tags: macos, facetime

Before High Sierra, I had the ability to automatically accept FaceTime calls in Mac OS X (within com.apple.FaceTime.plist).
After I had a chat today with an Apple supporter, I know that it no longer works with the following code (it has never been officially supported):

```
<key>AutoAcceptInvites</key>
<true/>
<key>AutoAcceptInvitesFrom</key>
<array>
 <string>myadress@foobar.com</string>
</array>
```

This functionality is very important for me. Does anybody know another workaround?

Comment: You should write what error you are getting:

From: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.